# jquery dialog widget not work with onclick button in row table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have table like image bellow where i create from query to databases, each row have button i want when onclick will be prompt dialog box (i use jquery dialog widget)
[image: image 1]

this my php code to create the table

```
while ($fetch_dbsi_mhsw=mysql_fetch_array($query_dbsi_mhsw)) {
$no++;
echo" <tr>
<td>$no</td>
<td>$fetch_dbsi_mhsw[NIM]</td>
<td>$fetch_dbsi_mhsw[Name]</td>
<td style=\"text-align: center;\"><input name=\"bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan\" id=\"bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan\" type=\"image\" src=\"buttonTambah.png\" alt=\"Tambah\" align=\"middle\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\"  /></td>  </tr>";}
```

and my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan").click(function(){
    var value1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var value2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    // Here's the text of the dialog box 
    var dialog = $("<div style='display: none'><p>Anda akan menambahkan "+value1 + " " + value2 + " sebagai calon wisudawan?</p></div>").appendTo("body");
    // This is the button on the form
    var form = $("#form_tambah_cl_wisudawan")
    // The form button was pressed - open the dialog
    $(dialog).dialog(
    {
            title: "Konvirmasi Penambahan Data",
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Tambah": function () {
                    // This will invoke the form's action - putatively deleting the resources on the server
                    $(form).submit();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    // Don't invoke the action, just close the dialog
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

});

my problem is when i click plus button in row number one the dialog box will appear (like image 2) 
[image: image 2]

but why  when i click plus button in another row the dialog box not appear, the page just reload and my table is gone.i want to prompt dialog box whenever i click  one of the pluss button. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you use duplicate identifiers, **Identifiers must be unique.** You can add a common CSS class then can use class selector `$('.className')`

*HTML(Simplified here)*

```
<input class="bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan" />
```

*Script*

```
$(".bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan").click(function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        value1 = tr.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
        value2 = tr.find('td:eq(2)').text();

    //rest of code
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this solve my problem, but where is my duplicate identifier?sory my bad english.

Comment: @eniac05, You are generating ID is a while loop so `id=\"bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan\"` is generated multiple times